# DRYing up string assignment

Tags: c, embedded

Below is one of my C functiosn:

```
void test(char * ptr)
{
    ptr[0] = 'T';
    ptr[1] = 'O';
    ptr[2] = 'P';
    ptr[3] = '\0';
}
```

Is there a way to shorten this? I've tried

```
void test(char * ptr)
{
    ptr[0] = "TOP";
}
```

but that doesn't work. [Note: I do not have the library function `strcpy()` or similar.]

Comment: If you don't have a `strcpy`, you may want to write one. It's pretty much a one liner.

Comment: `*((int*)ptr) = 'T' << 24 | 'O' << 16 | 'P' << 8;`

Comment: @RoyDictus No that would make ptr point to a string literal.  Not the same thing.

Comment: @Yossarian That only works on a big endian machine, on an little endian machine memory would be '\0', 'P', 'O', 'T'.

Comment: @Yossarian, @Fred: in addition to endianness issues, it breaks on platforms which are less forgiving of unaligned access; it's actually UB - if the `ptr` argument doesn't point to an `int`, the assignment will violate effective typing (aka strict aliasing)

Comment: What does "DRYing" mean?

Comment: @Clifford: "DRY" means "don't repeat yourself": http://c2.com/cgi/wiki?DontRepeatYourself

Comment: Thanks Michael; if that is common knowledge (world-wide), then I am embarrassed.  If not then a better question title would be in order.  I suggest if I have never come across the acronym in 22 years of embedded systems development, then probably the latter.  The principle is of course very familiar.

Comment: @Clifford: I think "DRY" is a pretty well known term in the 'agile' community, but I don't think it's 'common knowledge'. I think that strictly speaking the question isn't about the DRY principle, since it's not really about having knowledge of the "TOP" string in more than one place. This question is really about  finding a more natural/less ugly way to initialize or assign to a character array in C without having a runtime library `strcpy()`.  Maybe a title of "How to assign a new value to a char array without `strcpy()`"?

Comment: @Micheal: I am familiar with the principle, but not perhaps the acronym.  Let's hope the Agileists don't think they've invented something new here - other than another dumb pointless TLA perhaps ;-).  It certainly seems to be misused here - where the simple and somewhat obvious answer is write your own string copy.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you need to write your own strcpy().  You can only do `char ptr[] = "TOP"` for initializers.

But you can do this which can easily be changed to strcpy():

```
void test(char * ptr)
{
    char * S_TOP = "TOP";

    do {
        *ptr++ = *S_TOP++;
    } while( *S_TOP != '\0' );
}
```

Answer (score 7):

Assuming GCC, take a look at the list of [built-in functions](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/gcc/Other-Builtins.html). In particular, both `__builtin_strcpy()` and `__builtin_memcpy()` are available as compiler instrinsics and need no library support.